# How do I keep a background positioned when browser is resized?

Tags: html, css, firefox, dreamweaver

I'm using a background image on my site that needs to stay in place. This works save for when the page is viewed with Firefox. When the Firefox window is sized smaller than the background image it begins to push the background. You can see what I mean here: http://www.dev.arbitersoflight.net/ (Watch the head of the woman.)

Here's the CSS for the body, which contains the image:

```
body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background: #0b0e13 url(/img/backs/bg_tSm.jpg) no-repeat center top;


   width: 100%;
   display: table;  
}
```

I read an article that mentioned this is happens in Firefox, and that the two returns in the code are meant to fix it...but it didn't. Thanks in advance.

Comment: works fine for me in FF v3.6.13 ..?

Comment: You could just put the head back onto the rest of the "Join us" image, and it'd look fine.

Comment: Looks fine to me in Chrome on Linux as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working a few minutes ago. The fix was to add a "min-width" to the html style giving me:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1200px;
}
```

Comment: If this works for you, accept it as the answer so that others don't waste time reading a solved question.